# How to get an Object from $cookies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cookies, npm

I'm storing a user object on a Cookie and, when the client visit the site again, I want to use this object's properties.

But, when the client comes back, my cookie object looks like `[object object]`  while it's properties looks like `undefined`.

Here is my code:

```
$scope.signup = function (user) {
    $http.post('/api/signup', user)
        .then( function (res) {
            $cookies.put('user', res.data.user); //This is where I store my cookie.
        }, function (res) {

        });
};
```

When the client comes back, I have this code:

```
var lastUser = $cookies.get('user');
if (lastUser) $scope.lastName = lastUser.username;
console.log(lastUser);  // [object object]
console.log(lastName); // undefined
```

What can I do to properly get the cookie info?

Comment: cookie to store an object is a BAD idea. Use local storage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me why, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies

Comment: Thanks, @epascarello I will read that.

Comment: Cookies only store strings, not objects.  So, you have to put your data into string form before putting it into a cookie.  if your data isn't a simple string or number, you can use `JSON.stringify()` on an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res.data.user));
```

Then you can get that information on consequent visits with:

```
var userData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

That way you'll avoid a lot of the cookie headache.

Comment: Thanks, @HunanRostomyan I'm going to try it now.